# Update an array sort order based on a user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to write a javascript function that allows a user to input the sort order where they want an object to go AND then fix the position that has that sort order at the time

```
var object = [{
  sortOrder: 4,
  id: "braves"
},{
  sortOrder: 2,
  id: "cubs"
},{
  sortOrder: 3,
  id: "marlins"
},{
  sortOrder: 1,
  id: "mets"
}]
```

The user request that the id: "braves" be moved to sortOrder: 1.

So it would put the "braves" at sortOrder 1 and then add 1 to the mets, cubs, marlins and the order would be: braves, mets, cubs, marlins now.

I've looked at the sort() function but it appears it just sorts it. And if both the mets and braves have sortOrder of 1 now, then how does it know which one should be first compared to 2nd?

What is the best way to handle this in jquery/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this,

```
function moveOrder(id,position){
    object.find(item=>item.id===id).sortOrder=position;
    object.forEach(item=>{
        if(item.id!==id && item.sortOrder>=position)
            item.sortOrder=item.sortOrder+1;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const object = [
    {
        sortOrder: 4,
        id: 'braves',
    },
    {
        sortOrder: 2,
        id: 'cubs',
    },
    {
        sortOrder: 3,
        id: 'marlins',
    },
    {
        sortOrder: 1,
        id: 'mets',
    },
];

function sortObject(id, nextSortOrder) {
    return object.map((o) => {
        if (o.id === id) {
            return Object.assign({}, o, { sortOrder: nextSortOrder });
        }

        return Object.assign({}, o, {
            sortOrder: o.sortOrder === object.length ? 1 : o.sortOrder + 1,
        });
    });
}

const sortedObject = sortObject('brave', 1);
console.log(sortedObject);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. Nice to see many different ways!

Answer (score 1):

You can map your current array of objects to a new array of objects with each `sortOrder` incremented if it is greater than or equal to the provided `sortOrder`. Then you can find the object in your array with the `id` equal to the provided `id` using `.find()` so that you can change it's `sortOrder` to that of the provided `sortOrder`. Lastly, you can resort your new array:

```js
function sortArr(arr, _sortOrder, _id) {
  const new_arr = arr.map(({sortOrder, ...r}) => sortOrder >= _sortOrder ? {...r, sortOrder: sortOrder+1} : {...r, sortOrder});
  const obj = new_arr.find(({id}) => id === _id);
  obj.sortOrder = _sortOrder;
  
  return new_arr.sort(({sortOrder:a}, {sortOrder:b}) => b-a);;
}

const arr = [{sortOrder:4,id:"braves"},{sortOrder:2,id:"cubs"},{sortOrder:3,id:"marlins"},{sortOrder:1,id:"mets"}];

console.log(sortArr(arr, 1, "braves"));
```